# Não consigo receber url no php usando htaccess

Tags: htaccess

Este é o código que estou usando, porem ele não envia a url para o arquivo sapatos.php, mas eu coloco o arquivo index.php e ele envia.

Como resolver isso? Ou seja como enviar a URL para o arquivo sapatos.php?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ sapatos.php?url=$1
```

Comment: Explica melhor o que você quer fazer? Essa regrinha me parece toda errada ou não compreendi o que está tentando! Abraços

Comment: Esse video do youtube 
 to seguindo ele v=BWQ5vzd_G_c&t=272s&list=LLSUwdRmyEwvcKgfztSet0cA&index=8